# How to get all tag names?

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

```
names = await self.client.db.fetch("SELECT trigger FROM tags WHERE guild_id = $1", ctx.guild.id)
await ctx.send(names)
```

```
[<Record trigger='hoe'>, <Record trigger='guild'>, <Record trigger='err'>, <Record trigger='ikr'>, <Record trigger='ikr'>, <Record trigger='ew'>, <Record trigger='raid'>, <Record trigger='brake'>, <Record trigger="Spen's profile">]
```

How do I only get all tag names like ikr, guild, ew

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using `asyncpg`.

In asyncpg, the `fetch` coroutine returns a list of `asyncpg.Record` objects and in this case each Record object has a `trigger` field. So you want to iterate over each record in the result from the DB fetch and use the value for the "trigger" field.

To make it easy, you can just replace each item in the fetch results list with the value of its trigger field, which can be done simply in Python with enumeration:

```py
names = await self.client.db.fetch("SELECT trigger FROM tags WHERE guild_id = $1", ctx.guild.id)
for index, record in enumerate(names):
    names[index] = record["trigger"]
await ctx.send(names)
# should send "['hoe', 'guild', 'err', ... ]"
```

Comment: it sends a list i want it to send just names like hoe, guild and err

Comment: If you mean so that the Discord message is "hoe, guild, err, ..." then you can use Python's string.join(): `", ".join(names)` will return a string like you want – so do `await ctx.send(", ".join(names))`

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` in asyncpg returns a Record object that is subscriptable, we can simply use list comprehension to convert into a string.

```py
names = await self.client.db.fetch("SELECT trigger FROM tags WHERE guild_id = $1", ctx.guild.id)
names = [x['trigger'] for x in names]

await ctx.send(names)
#names will be ['ikr', 'guild', 'ew'] in your case
```

### References:

- [asyncpg.fetch](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=fetch#asyncpg.connection.Connection.fetch)
- [Record objects](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=fetch#asyncpg.Record)

Note: if you want to use the same thing for all the fetches, I suggest looking into the `record_class` parameter for connections or fetches.